# How to use the Email template in c#code in kentico 10

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc, kentico-api

I created one Email template in Kentico 10.

1. How to use the Email template in c#code.

   2. I created the one kentico cms form, once submit the form after I need to show the success message in popup window.
      how to do?

Answer (score 0):

The Kentico Docs site has some great examples.  Here's the page for the Email API:
https://docs.kentico.com/api10/on-line-marketing/email-marketing

What have you tried with the form submit?

After saving of the form data you probably want to fire some code that registers javascript to show the appropriate modal.

An example of adding a handler with custom code:
https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/miscellaneous-custom-development-tasks/working-with-form-data-using-the-api

Some example javascript for modifying modal classes for display:
https://devnet.kentico.com/forums/f68/t43078/popup-windows

There should also be plenty examples on how to register the client script if you need that to.